# Template String and Interpolation String in Javascript ES6 don't Working

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation, frontend

**Its appear be so simple use but its dont work in my Chrome Browser. Can someone help me?**

That's my code:

```
var a = "Something";
Var b = "is";
console.log('${a} ${b} wrong.');
```

I did put this code in console in chrome browser but its dont worked how should work.

Comment: You need backticks, (``), not quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use backtick.

```js
let a = "Something";
let b = "is";
console.log(`${a} ${b} wrong.`);
```